# Finding out variable class and difference between Hash and Array

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to clearly identify a class of variable?

something like:

```
@users.who_r_u? #=>Class (some information)

@packs.who_r_u? #=> Array (some information)
```

etc.

Can someone provide clear short explanation of difference between Class, Hash, Array, Associated Array, etc. ?

Comment: still want to find clear simple explanation of difference between them all. thanx

Comment: A hash and an associative array are the same thing. A Class is an object's type that contains a collection of methods. The class of a Hash is Hash and Array is Array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
@users.class
```

Test it in irb:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > 1.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.3p0 :002 > "1".class
 => String
1.9.3p0 :003 > [1].class
 => Array 
1.9.3p0 :004 > {:a => 1}.class
 => Hash 
1.9.3p0 :005 > (1..10).class
 => Range
```

Or:

```
1.9.3p0 :010 > class User
1.9.3p0 :011?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p0 :012 > @user = User.new
 => #<User:0x0000010111bfc8> 
1.9.3p0 :013 > @user.class
 => User
```

These were only quick irb examples, hope it's enough to see the use of .class in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `kind_of?` to test wheter its  receiver is a class, an array or anything else.

```
 @users.kind_of?(Array) # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

A difference between `Class` and `Hash`? They are too different to even provide normal answer. `Hash` is basically an array with unique keys, where each key has its associated value. That's why it's also called associative array.

Here is some explanation:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
array[0] # => 1
array[-1] # => 4
array[0..2] # => [1,2,3]
array.size # => 4
```

Check out more `Array` methods here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

```
hash = {:foo => 1, :bar => 34, :baz => 22}
hash[:foo] # => 1
hash[:bar] # => 34
hash.keys # => [:baz,:foo,:bar] 
hash.values # => [34,22,1]
hash.merge :foo => 3921
hash # => {:bar => 34,:foo => 3921,:baz => 22 }
```

`Hash` never keeps order of the elments you added to it, it just preserves uniqueness of keys, so you can easily retreive values.

However, if you do this:

```
 hash.merge "foo" => 12
```

you will get

```
 hash # => {:bar => 34, baz => 22, "foo" => 12, :foo => 2}
```

It created new key-value pair since `:foo.eql? "foo"` returns `false`.

For more `Hash` methods check out this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html

`Class` object is a bit too complex to explain in short, but if you want to learn more about it, reffer to some online tutorials.

And remember, API is your friend.

Comment: thank you very much! great explanation! I will definitely read resources suggested by you

Comment: Ruby *does* have associative arrays aka maps aka dictionaries, but for some strange reason they are called `Hash`.

Comment: you welcome. @JörgWMittag I've updated my post accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these methods in Ruby document http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html

```
@user.class => User
@user.is_a?(User) => true
@user.kind_of?(User) => true
```

Answer (score 0):

found helpful: `<%= debug @users %>`